# Adding pdf preview to post

Tags: wordpress

I need to add ability to add pdf files to users. The best way, that I found, is google-document-embedder plugin. But it can only add preview by link, but users should have ability to upload pdf and automatically insert preview short code. Does any solution exist?

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to generate an url:
https://docs.google.com/viewer

and be sure to use the option embedded=true. This will generate a preview.

How to use:

<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=**YourUrlHere**&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>

Comment: no-no. there should be an ability for users to select file on computer and automatically put code to page

Comment: Simply upload the file and use the iframe to display a preview. I edited the answer to show it more clearly.

Comment: I can just repeat. Users should have ability to choose file from computer and AUTOMATICALLY insert shortcode to editor. WITHOUT writing o copying code themselves. Just click "insert" and code is in the post. Something like this.

Comment: Then you are searching for a tool, which is off-topic for this site.

Comment: When you load file and click "insert", wordpress automatically inserts html code with simple link to your post. I think I can edit wordpress code to change "a" to "embed" or "iframe" for pdf uploads. Searching and changing this code is not offtopic